# Using UV to kill bacteria in shoes

Tags: bacteriology, light, dna-damage, sterilisation, uv

I see that UV-C is the best to kill bacteria generally. We are interested in using to kill off odor in shoes.

What illuminance is needed to kill most bacteria with UV-C?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Only the last of the three questions relates to biology. The others are questions of material physics.

Comment: Do people still use the foot-candle in the USA? The standard unit of illuminance is the [lux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux). Note that once you know the illuminance on the target, finding out the illuminance at a given distance is quite basic (and is a question of physics/math). I would recommend you restrict your whole question to something like "What illuminance is needed to kill most bacteria with UV-C?".

Comment: Close vote retracted and +1.

Answer (score 1):

The wavelength of UV-C most effective at provoking mutagenesis in DNA is 260 nm, which has been shown to kill *Cryptosporidium parvum* at doses below 10 mJ/sq cm.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12834745

In units of lux, 10^5 lux of sunlight has been shown to kill 99.9% of *Aeromonas salmonicida* after two hours of exposure.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0043135499001591